# What is the tenant ID for The Thing Network au1 region?

Tags: lorawan, ttn

I have created an application in my TTN account. The region is Australia 1(Sydney).

I want to integrate this application with AWS iOT core for LoraWan. Following TTN integration guide, I was automatically directed to the CloudFormation>Stacks>Create Stack. Where it asks for a cluster address like ..cloud.thethings.industries

I could not find the value for , can anybody advise where to get the value for ?

Answer (score 0):

select "sandbox" environment The Things Stack deployment guide for AWS CloudFormation Template